# How can I use JavaScript to show results to my personality quiz?

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a one question personality quiz that will alert the user with their personality after clicking submit. My form tells the user their personality after clicking their favorite coffee. I am a beginner when it comes to JavaScript, so I am not sure what kind of function to use when it comes to using radio buttons. Does alert(" "); have a max word count? is there a better way to show a lengthy personality result?

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Coffee with Coincidence</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="coffee.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="CoffeeForm" onsubmit="return getResults()" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Cappuccino</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="coffee" value="cappuccino" id="cappuccino"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Caffè Americano</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="coffee" value="caffèamericano" id="caffeamericano"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Latte</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="coffee" value="latte" id="latte"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Espresso</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="coffee" value="espresso" id="espresso">
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Caffè mocha</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="coffee" value="caffèmocha" id="caffemocha"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="Submit" value="Results!"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <script src="coffeeScripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is a fail test of JavaScript I tried to do if a cappuccino was selected.

```
function getResults() {
  var x = document.getElementById("cappuccino");

  if (x == "checked") {
    alert("Cappuccino personality goes here");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: An error no answerer has mentioned yet is where you check `if (x == "checked")` -- here `x` is an `HTMLElement` _Object_ ... you can't compare it to a String. Since it is a _radio button_ you see if it's selected by using `if (x.checked)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **innerHTML** to set the contents of an HTML Element. After your user finishes the quiz you can return the desired answer to an HTML element.

HTML

```
<p id="result"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
const result = document.getElementById('result');
const answer = "Cappuccino personality goes here";
result.innerHTML = answer;
```

Comment: Should I put <p id="result"></p> before or after the script? Do I add the JavaScript to mine?

Comment: That is a paragraph HTML tag, **innerHTML**  can be used with other HTML elements. Add an **id** selector like I did to the element. Also yes add the javascript to yours, just add the variables outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Display Personality details through alert**

You can just use a selector to select an input that is checked then use its value to know what it is.

```js
function getResults() {

    var x = document.querySelector("input:checked");
    switch (x.value) {
      case "cappuccino":
        alert("Cappuccino personality goes here");
        break;
      case "caffèamericano":
        alert("Caffèamericano personality goes here");
        break;
      case "latte":
        alert("Latte personality goes here");
        break;
      case "espresso":
        alert("Espresso personality goes here");
        break;
      case "caffèmocha":
        alert("Caffèmocha personality goes here");
        break;
      default:

    }
  return false;
  }
```

```html
<form id="CoffeeForm" onsubmit="return getResults()" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Cappuccino</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="coffee" value="cappuccino" id="cappuccino"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Caffè Americano</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="coffee" value="caffèamericano" id="caffeamericano"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Latte</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="coffee" value="latte" id="latte"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Espresso</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="coffee" value="espresso" id="espresso">
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Caffè mocha</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="coffee" value="caffèmocha" id="caffemocha"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="Submit" value="Results!"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

2. **Display Personality details through `div`**

If you want to display the personality details in HTML you can use a div.

```js
function getResults() {
    var hidden_divs = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden-div");
    for (var i = 0; i < hidden_divs.length; i++) {
      hidden_divs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    var x = document.querySelector("input:checked");
    var display_div = document.getElementsByName(x.value)[0].style.display = "block";
  return false;
  }
```

```css
  .hidden-div{
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<form id="CoffeeForm" onsubmit="return getResults()" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Cappuccino</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="coffee" value="cappuccino" id="cappuccino"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Caffè Americano</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="coffee" value="caffèamericano" id="caffeamericano"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Latte</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="coffee" value="latte" id="latte"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Espresso</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="coffee" value="espresso" id="espresso">
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Caffè mocha</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="coffee" value="caffèmocha" id="caffemocha"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="Submit" value="Results!"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <div class="Personality-text-div">
    <div name="cappuccino" class="hidden-div">
      <strong>Cappuccino</strong><br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div name="affèamericano" class="hidden-div">
      <strong>Affèamericano</strong><br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div name="latte" class="hidden-div">
      <strong>Latte</strong><br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div name="espresso" class="hidden-div">
      <strong>Espresso</strong><br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div name="caffèmocha" class="hidden-div">
      <strong>Caffèmocha</strong><br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
```